# VS2013 compiling and linking ngspice as a shared library

Tags: c++, visual-studio

Does a comprehensive tutorial on how to compile ngspice using Visual Studio exist?

I downloaded the source and it includes a sln file.
I opened and converted it to vs2013.

Compiling and linking generates about 2000 warnings and a couple of errors.
I need ngspice to simulate electronics for integration testing.

NGSpice Tutorials focus on using the GUI. I found little Information on the API. The website states the first step is to download the tar ball and compile it. I am running into trouble with that fist step and I got stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They have a manual in their documentation:
*"Can be done, but is tedious. I will describe my procedure on Windows 7, 64 Bit Home Edition."*

http://ngspice.sourceforge.net/docs/ngspice-manual.pdf
Chapter 20.6.2

Comment: Wow, "tedious", no kidding. 5 hours later and I still have yet to compile and run a hello world with this. This takes ages.

Answer (score 1):

Download ngspice26 sources from
http://sourceforge.net/projects/ngspice/files/ng-spice-rework/26/ngspice-26.tar.gz/download

Two changes have to be made to file
ngspice-26/src/include/ngspice/ngspice.h

comment out line 179

```
//#define isnan _isnan
```

add e.g. at line 201

```
// undo a #define bool _Bool in MS Visual Studio 2015
#if defined(bool)
#undef bool
#endif
```

Then ngspice.dll will result from compilation with VS2015.

A more recent version, ready to compile with VS2015 by one click on sharedspice.vcxproj, is available from git by

```
git clone git://ngspice.git.sourceforge.net/gitroot/ngspice/ngspice
```

B.t.w. chapter 20.6.2 of the manual is about tclspice, a different thing, using ngspice in a tcl/tk environment.

Comment: Thanks. I will try this soon.